Cypress add an option optionally
I have this case for example:

cy.get('input[type=file]').selectFile('myFile', {action: 'drag-drop',
force: true})

In some cases i do not need to pass the option action and force.
How can i use the same command but add the options optionally please.
====
Edited Question
i want to put this in a command like below:

cypress.commands.add("selectMyFile", (myFile) => {
cy.get('input[type=file]').selectFile(myFile) })

But in certain cases i want to use the same command but add the options to it.
Is there a possibility for calling my command like below:

cy.selectMyFile("myfile.jpg", {action: "drag-drop"})

Thank you

I don't get what you are asking - they are called "options" because they are optional. If you don't want to use them, don't pass them. Please clarify with some examples.

i have edited my question can you please check.

To transfer the options for .selectFile() to a custom command, add them as a parameter to the custom command.
Cypress.Commands.add("selectMyFile", (myFile, options = {}) => {    
  cy.get('input[type=file]').selectFile(myFile, options) })
})

Using options = {} in the parameter list will allow the scenario where no options are passed in the test, in which case {} is an empty options object.
Used:
selectMyFile('my-file-name', {action: 'drag-drop'})

To have some different default, say you want default drag-drop (the current default is select)
Cypress.Commands.add("selectMyFile", (myFile, options = {}) => {    

  /*
    set whatever defaults you need in this object
    here I just set `force:true`, 
    but the others can be un-commented if desired
  */
  const defaultOptions = {
    force: true,
    // action: 'drag-drop',
    // log: false, 
    // timeout: 10000, 
  }

  /* 
    make actual options equal defaultOptions, 
    but override with any options values passed from the test
  */
  options = {
    ...defaultOptions,   
    ...options,
  }
  cy.get('input[type=file]').selectFile(myFile, options) 
})

Used:
selectMyFile('my-file-name')   // action will be "drag-drop" since no option given

selectMyFile('my-file-name', {action: 'select', force: true}) // give options


Thank you. What if i want to do use force: true in the command always?
like this:
cypress.commands.add("selectMyFile", (myFile) => { cy.get('input[type=file]').selectFile(myFile), {force: true }) but other options like drag-drop can be added optionally.

cy.get('input[type=file]').selectFile(myFile, {force:true}, options)  should do the work i think

Yes, I'll update.

they already are optional, the options are everything in the braces so you just have to remove them, aswell as the comma as you don't give anything else with it. Your code therefore would be
cy.get('input[type=file]').selectFile('myFile')

and as Jen already mentioned, 'option' means 'freedom of choice' and therefore means optional. You can also read more about it here

I have edited my question can you please check?
